# codeigniter HMVC extension model organization

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am developing a portal and using codeigniter with HMVC extension. I have an "admin" module and a "yellowpages" module. Both these modules have a common model eg: "Category_model", and I use it to list down the categories both in the frontend(yellowpages) and backend(admin) module.

So my question is, can I place the model in the application/models directory and have it accessed by both the modules, or do I have to copy the model and place each copy inside /modules/admin/models and /modules/yellowpages/models

Answer (score 1):

> Resources may be cross loaded between
>   modules. ie:
>   $this->load->model(‘module/model’);

More info [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) and [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/)